# Can the Shopify Mobile Buy SDK do anything that the Storefront GraphQL API can't?

Tags: flutter, shopify, mobile-application

I'm currently working on creating a mobile app for my store.  I'm reading the docs and there is one thing I don't understand.

I need to create queries and mutations via GraphQL.  For example, the mutation might be [checkoutCreate](https://shopify.dev/docs/storefront-api/reference/mutation/checkoutcreate).  I can also [Query Objects](https://shopify.dev/docs/storefront-api/reference/object) (for example Checkouts)

Then again, I found this piece of information:

> Storefront
>
> Using the [Mobile Buy SDK](https://shopify.dev/tools/libraries/storefront-api/mobile) for iOS and Android, you can access storefront data such as customers, store resources, and checkouts. When building checkout experiences, you can choose from a variety of ways to complete payments for maximum flexibility and limited PCI liability.

Why would I use the Mobile Buy SDK when I can Query and Mutate everything I need?
I'm developing on Flutter so I need to know whether I can create the app without the Mobile Buy SDK.
I feel like I misunderstood something.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand are the Mobile Buy SDKs just API wrappers

Maybe take a look at [flutter_simple_shopify](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_simple_shopify) ([GitHub](https://github.com/ThinkSimple/flutter_simple_shopify)) for an existing wrapper for flutter

Comment: You have not provided a complete answer to the question. And consider the grammar too. Please, refer to the [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to improve your answer.